# Comparar el mismo ARRAY chars y que muestre por pantalla los elementos que no se repiten en JAVA

Tags: java, array

soy nuevo con los arrays en java, y el problema es el siguiente: tengo el siguiente array = {'A','B','B','C'}
y como la 'B' se repite dos veces, quiero que me muestre el siguiente array = {'A','B','C'}
Alguna sugerencia / ayuda

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] a = {'A','B','B','C'};

    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
          //no compare las posiciones i=j
          if (a[i]!=a[j]){                        
              
          }
          }
        
        }


}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué dificultades tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta, agregando lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora. De paso, pon el título de la pregunta usando mayúsculas /  minúsculas adecuadamente.

Comment: Perdona @A.Cedano, creo que ya he puesto adecuadamente todo, gracias !
Lo que estoy intentado hacer es comparar el mismo array consigo mismo, es decir, que coja la posicion 0 = 'A', y que la compare con todo el array de nuevo, menos con la posición 0.

En caso de que no se repita, que el búcle siga, y en caso de que se repita, que elimine esa letra y muestre por pantalla, todo el array, menos las letras que se repiten

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un Array debes tener en cuenta que este tiene un tamaño estático por lo cual primero debes obtener el nuevo tamaño que tendrá un nuevo Array donde guardaras los elementos sin repetir

Ejemplo:

```
     char[] a = {'A','B','B','C','C','B','A'};
    //ordenamos el array para tener los valor A A B B B C C
      Arrays.sort(a);
      int j = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
//usamos una condicional para evaluar los elementos distintos y la cantida que
//estos representan
           if(a[i]!=a[i+1]){
              a[j++] = a[i];
           }
       }
    //obtenemos el nuevo tamaño que ocupara los valores sin repetir
       a[j++] = a[a.length-1];
    //declaramos el array con el nuevo tamaño
       char [] c = new char[j];
    //pasamos los elementos del array a sin repetir al nuevo array c
       for(int k = 0;k<j;k++){
          c[k] = a[k];
       }
    
      
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si esto no es un ejercicio, quizá hay formas más simples de lograr lo que quieres usando por ejemplo [expresiones lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), disponibles desde la versión 8 de Java.

Para permanecer lo más fieles posible a un eventual contexto de ejercicio, lo primero que debes considerar es que en Java no es posible modificar de forma dinámica el tamaño de un array, porque los mismos deben ser declarados con un [tamaño fijo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3). Significa que, antes de crear el nuevo array con los `char` no repetidos, debes saber de algún modo cuántos hay, al tiempo que debes ir coleccionando uno de cada.

La forma más simple que se me ocurre consiste en crear una cadena temporal, ir verificando si cada carácter no existe antes en ella para agregarlo y luego convertir esa cadena en un nuevo array de caracteres.

#### Código:

```
    char[] a = {'A','B','B','C'}; 
    String tmp = ""; //Cadena temporal
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        /*
            Si el char no existe indexOf retorna -1
            significa que podemos agregarlo a tmp
        */
        if(tmp.indexOf(a[i]) == -1) {
            tmp = tmp+a[i];   
        }
    }
    /*
        Llamando a toCharArray() convertimos tmp
        en un array de char
    */
    char[] b=tmp.toCharArray();
    //Prueba
    System.out.println(b);
```

**Salida:**

```
ABC
```